# Sparql for events in dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am new to SPARQL, and trying to query event data on DBPedia whose source articles are in Dutch.

How could I query type of events, count numbers of each event type? Please advise. 
I am using http://dbpedia.org/sparql because http://events.dbpedia.org/sparql won't work.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'm adding my query as advised.
Is the following the correct query to count `MilitaryConflict` events?

```
SELECT (count(distinct ?event) as ?cnt)
WHERE{?event a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/MilitaryConflict> .
}
```

Comment: Please see, and learn from, [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)... Figuring out queries like this is often made much easier by looking at an example of the thing you want to find more of -- so you can see what attributes it has, which you can use to find others... What is an example "event"? Have you tried any queries? What were they? What results did you get, and how did those differ from what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks @TallTed . I was struggling to add the query cuz it told me to indent properly. I have added a query on the post, and I am assuming it is the correct one to count MilitaryConflict events, is it right?

Comment: @TallTed I am now adding Filter for time periods. It works when I am not adding filter for language, but as I have both language filter and time period filter, it gets an error... I added: dbo:date ?date . FILTER ( ?date >= "1960-01-01"^^xsd:date && ?date <= "2018-12-31"^^xsd:date ) .

Comment: This should be a new question, where you should put your full new queries -- (1) with just language filter, (2) with just date filter, and (3) with both language and date filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your query is correct to count entities of type `dbo:MilitaryConflict`.

Here are a couple other queries, starting from yours, which should help you continue...

[query 1](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%28%20COUNT%20%28DISTINCT%20%3Fabs%29%20AS%20%3Fcnt%20%29%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fevent%20%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AMilitaryConflict%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%20%3Fabs%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20LANGMATCHES%20%28%20LANG%28%3Fabs%29%20%2C%20%22nl%22%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) ([results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%28%20COUNT%20%28DISTINCT%20%3Fabs%29%20AS%20%3Fcnt%20%29%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fevent%20%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AMilitaryConflict%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%20%3Fabs%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20LANGMATCHES%20%28%20LANG%28%3Fabs%29%20%2C%20%22nl%22%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20))--

```
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT 
    ( COUNT (DISTINCT ?abs) AS ?cnt )
WHERE
  { ?event  a             dbo:MilitaryConflict ;
            dbo:abstract  ?abs .
    FILTER ( LANGMATCHES ( LANG(?abs) , "nl" ) )
}
```

-- and [query 2](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20DISTINCT%20%3Fevent%20%3Fabs%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fevent%20%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AMilitaryConflict%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%20%3Fabs%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20LANGMATCHES%20%28%20LANG%28%3Fabs%29%20%2C%20%22nl%22%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) ([results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20DISTINCT%20%3Fevent%20%3Fabs%20%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%3Fevent%20%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AMilitaryConflict%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%20%3Fabs%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20LANGMATCHES%20%28%20LANG%28%3Fabs%29%20%2C%20%22nl%22%20%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20))--

```
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT 
    DISTINCT ?event ?abs 
WHERE
  { ?event  a             dbo:MilitaryConflict ;
            dbo:abstract  ?abs .
    FILTER ( LANGMATCHES ( LANG(?abs) , "nl" ) )
}
```

***NOTE*** -- The "Default Graph" value in the SPARQL form (which becomes the `default-graph-uri=` query argument in the links you'll click above) must be left blank, to get results for all languages.

Comment: Oh thank you!! You shed light for me :-) Will try to learn from it.